# Firestore increment is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have the following trigger, having a hard time doing an increment on a parent field.
Any suggestions?

```html
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const fieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onTicketCreate = functions.firestore
  .document('/contests/{contestId}/{tickets}/{ticketId}')
  .onWrite((snapshot, context) => { 

    functions.firestore.document('contests/' + context.params.contestId).update({
        points: fieldValue.increment(1)
    });
  });
```

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'increment' of undefined
at exports.onTicketCreate.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/workspace/lib/index.js:27:48)
at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:132:23)
at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: It's not `increment` that is undefined, but `FieldValue`. I don't immediately see why that is though. Just as a test, can you try `points: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)`?

Comment: I will also point out that you can't query firestore using the `functions` constant.  That's just for building the function.  You will need to use `admin.firestore()` to get a reference to a Firestore instance that can do a query.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly not sure why that didn't work, but I got it to work with this code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.waitReportCreatedJS = functions.firestore
    .document('/contests/{contestId}/{tickets}/{ticketId}') 
    .onWrite((snapshot, context) => { 

    admin.firestore().doc('contests/' + context.params.contestId)
        .update({ points: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) })
        .then(() => console.log('this will succeed'))
        .catch(() => 'obligatory catch');
});
```

Comment: I had this problem too, when I had defined increment as  `const increment = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` outside of the function.  Moving it inside fixed the problem.